# WinRT Deployment without microsoft store and NOT for internal use

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I need to deploy a custom made WinRT application that
1) Must be not available to the public (not on Microsoft store)
2) Must be installed on surface 3 that are not part of my company but dispatched in many companies using my software (provided on the tablets we include as part of the purchase). Those computers are NOT on our domain nor related to us in any way (we don't even own them, we sell them as part of each individual deal).

I'm really confused as to how i'm supposed to deploy in these circumstances, all i coudl find was solutions that violate 1 (just use the store) or 2 (sideloading for internal use in the company) or 2 again (sideloading and buying keys, which is silly i'm not paying 30$ each device to deploy my own application while clickonce was miles ahead and free and it still seems to be for internal use anyway).

Am i missing something obvious or is there like no proper and simple solution (like an installer => next => next bam it's installed) for winrt applications? Is there any way i can ship my WinRT app on a DVD? I'm open to any solutions but so far i'm pretty close to reverting to WPF just because of the deployment issues.

Comment: AFAIK (and input from others would probably be a good idea) you cannot do what you want to do due to the sandboxing model WinRT apps use

Comment: @IrisClasson Can you elaborate on that, or maybe refer me to some reading on why WinRT's sandboxing model prevents more conventional distribution? I'm curious about this.